# list of permissions included in a permission set?

Tags: force.com, security, permissions

I want to see which permissions are included in one of my permission sets. is there a way to get them all at once? Best I can see is that you have to go through 5- 6 different screens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can likely gather all of the information which you're looking for by querying the `PermissionSet`, `PermissionSetAssignment` and `ObjectPermissions` objects.

> Running the following query in SOQL will return both permission sets
>   you've created and permission sets parented by a profile:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id,IsOwnedByProfile,Label
> FROM PermissionSet
> ```
>
> By adding IsOwnedByProfile to the WHERE clause, you will quickly
>   differentiate between permission sets you've created versus those
>   parented by a profile:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id,IsOwnedByProfile,Label
> FROM PermissionSet
> WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = TRUE
> ```
>
> Once you have the hang of this, you can start to answer all sorts of
>   questions about your users such as, "which users have Read on Accounts
>   and why":
>
> ```
> SELECT Assignee.Name, PermissionSet.Id, 
>     PermissionSet.isOwnedByProfile, PermissionSet.Profile.Name, PermissionSet.Label
> FROM PermissionSetAssignment
> WHERE PermissionSetId
> IN (SELECT ParentId
> FROM ObjectPermissions
> WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND
> PermissionsRead = true)
> ```
>
> You might need to answer questions about a specific user such as,
>   "what are all of the Account fields where John Doe has at least Read
>   access and why"
>
> ```
> SELECT Id, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, Parent.label, Parent.IsOwnedByProfile
> FROM ObjectPermissions
> WHERE (ParentId
> IN (SELECT PermissionSetId
> FROM PermissionSetAssignment
> WHERE Assignee.Name = 'John Doe'))
> AND
> (PermissionsRead = true)
> AND
> (SobjectType = 'Account')
> ```
>
> Using permission sets in this way, you can find out why a user has
>   access to an apex page, class or a particular user, object, or field
>   permission, regardless of whether it's through their profile or
>   permission set.
>
> These SOQL queries are great if you have one off questions about your
>   user's permissions. If you have a more regular need to query user's
>   permissions, think about creating a Visualforce page with an Apex
>   controller that uses these queries to find out what your users can do
>   and why.

Via: [Using SOQL to Determine Your Force.com User's Permissions](http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html)