# how to check user have access to all sobjects

Tags: apex

here, my requirements i want to check user have whether authentication for all sobjects the corresponding fields, when a press a button called "check" , it should tell me whether the profile selected has a) read all the fields access b) edit the fieldss access c) delete the record  access, please send the sample code.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page Controller="checksobjectprofiles">  
<apex:form id="Describe">
  <apex:pageBlock id="block2" >
     <apex:pageblockbuttons location="top" >
        <apex:commandButton value="CHECK" action="{!checkFields}"/>
     </apex:pageblockbuttons>

   <apex:pageBlockSection title="SELECT INFO">
      <apex:selectList value="{!selecteduserId}" size="1" multiselect="false"  >
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfUser}" />

        </apex:selectList>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageblocksection >
      <apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}" size="1">
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectNames}"/>
      </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class checksobjectprofiles 
{

public List<SelectOption> ListOfUser {public get; private set; }

public String selecteduserId { get; set; }

 public string searchresult;
  public Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
  public List <SelectOption> objectNames{public get; private set;}
  public String selectedObject {get; set;}


public checksobjectprofiles () 
{
    objectNames = initObjNames();
     ListOfUser= initListOfUser();


}
private List<SelectOption> initObjNames() 
{
    List<SelectOption> objNames = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<String> entities = new List<String>(schemaMap.keySet());
    entities.sort();
    for(String name : entities)
    {
    objNames.add(new SelectOption(name,name));
    }
    return objNames;
}

private List<SelectOption> initListOfUser()
{
           List<User> Users = [select id ,Username,name from user] ;
           List<SelectOption> Ulist = new List<SelectOption>();
          // Ulist.add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
           for(User u : Users )
           {
                      Ulist.add(new SelectOption(u.Username ,u.UserName));
           }
          return Ulist ;
}

 public void checkFields() 
 {
    //fields.clear();
    system.debug('$$$$$' + selectedObject);
    list<string> sobjectfields = new list<string>();
    Map <String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(selectedObject).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values())
    {
    schema.describefieldresult fieldresult = sfield.getDescribe();
    system.debug('#######'  + fieldresult );   
    }
    searchresult='select'+'feildresult'+'from'+'selectedObject' +'where'+'id=:selecteduserId'; here i want to build dynamic soql 
    system.debug('*************'+searchresult);
}

}
```

Comment: This answer may be of assistance to you: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11538/660

Answer (score 5):

Since your using Apex Describe you can access this information at field level via the various methods on the [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_methods) class, such as **isAccessible()**, **isCreateable()**, **isUpdateable()**.

You can also get information at an object level, see methods on [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_methods), such as **isAccessible()**, **isCreateable()**, **isDeletable()**, **isUndeletable()**, **isQueryable()** and **isUpdateable()**.

Comment: Is there any way to get this DescribeFieldResult, but for some specific user (i.e. not the current one). We have a use case when admin has an option to sort of retry some pending user operation. So it's executed from admin context but we are trying to enforce security for that specific user.